# convert String to Json in android

Tags: android, json, string

in my android app i got an String from another device like this:

`String json = "[{'name', '11', '-0.5'}, {'name2', '-12', '0.5'}]";`

i want to convert this string to something like ArrayList or JsonObject or JsonArray to work with in my app

**I tried these ways but both of them throw me an Exception**

`JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(my_json_string);`

OR

`JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);`

how can i convert **string** to ArrayList or JsonObject to work with?

Comment: it is not a valid json. A Json contains always a pair of key/value. In your sample you have only keys or values

Comment: `throw me an Exception` - then **READ** that exception message with basic understanding maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions are probably because your json is not valid:

here is what should work:

```
 {"data": [{"who": "name", "age": "11", "diff":"-0.5"},
   {"who": "name2", "age": "12", "diff":"-1.5"}]}
```

to experiment with different formats you can use: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

This is an JsonArray of JsonObjects, so the code is:

```
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(my_json_string);
Model model;
JSONObject element;
for(int i = 0, len = jsonObj.length(); i < len; i++) {
    element = jsonObj.getJsonObject(i);
    model = new Model();
    model.setName(element.getString("name"));
    //..similarly set other properties
    list.add(model);
}
```

Now you have a list of compound models, Model.java is a separate data class with attributes.

Comment: thanks.i try that. but `JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(my_json_string);` this line throw me an Exception

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON format. Please refer to this [page](http://www.json.org/) to see how the correct JSON look like.

You also can use this [page](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to validate your JSON data.